# Upload multiple files in ionic Cordova using one HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, cordova, file-upload, upload, ionic-framework

I have seen ways to upload a file that originates from a `<form> <input>` but what I am trying to do in ionic is snap a photo using the camera plugin, then record audio using the media plugin and finally uploading both files in the same HTTP POST request.  I know how to snap the photo and record the audio.  I just need input on uploading both files in the same request.  Anyone have insight how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue with the following stackoverflow answer.  Hopefully this will help others out in the future.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25995009/4891914